# How does `getline` work in AWK?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I've put together an example using the AWK `getline` function and it's confusing me.

```
$ cat in
foo
bar
baz
$ awk '{ getline tmp; print tmp; print $0 }' in
bar
foo
bar
baz
```

I'm reading the next line into a variable named `tmp` which doesn't change `$0` as confirmed by the first two lines of output:

```
bar
foo
```

This is confirmed by the following table taken from [The AWK Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_AWK_Programming_Language) on page 62:

[image]

I know that the `NR` and `FNR` built-ins represent the number of lines read so far. I think this is the key to understanding what's going on but I'm confused how changing `NR` while in a pass affects future passes.

I was expecting the next two lines to be:

```
baz
bar
```

because on the second pass `$0 == bar` and `tmp == baz`.

Then I was expecting the next two lines to really only be one line:

```
baz
```

because on the third pass `$0 == baz` and `tmp == null`.

So my expected output is:

```
bar
foo
baz
bar
baz
```

I think understanding how changing `NR` while in the awk loop is the key to understanding this output.

- Can you explain why my expected output is wrong **and** why the actual output is right?

I'm running `awk version 20070501` on `macOS 10.12.1`

Comment: See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that, in setting `NR`, `getline` in effect *consumes* the line. So at the second invocation, `bar` is already gone and `$0` is `baz`; `getline` attempts to read another line and fails; and the value of `tmp` remains unchanged (i.e. equal to `bar`).

It may be easier to understand if you check the return value of `getline`:

```
awk '{ if ((getline tmp) > 0) print tmp; print $0 }' in
bar
foo
baz
```

Comment: So if I understand right: both `$0` and `getline tmp` use the value of `NR` to get their values. But `getline` increases `NR` and reaching the end of each invocation also increments `NR` so there really is only 2 invocations! In fact `$0` never sees `bar`, in my case, we see `bar` twice because it's still inside `tmp`. Wow, this is very subtle.

Comment: @mbigras yes I think that's correct - although I can't find a reference that actually states that the value of `tmp` is unmodified if `getline` fails (rather than, for example, being assigned the empty string). However there are people **much** more knowledgeable in awk than me on here - let's see if one of them chimes in.

Answer (score 1):

It should become clear if you look at the bigger picture, so to speak. An awk program is a loop around the program text, that reads one line then executes the program on this line. If you read a line inside the program, then the surrounding loop doesn't get to see this line: it's already been consumed.

For example, your program

```
{ getline tmp; print tmp; print $0 }
```

could be written as

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline $0) {
        getline tmp; print tmp; print $0
    }
}
```

The `BEGIN` block is executed once at the beginning of the program, and here the program doesn't do anything else — of course this is a highly non-idiomatic way of writing awk code.

Here it should be clear that what happens is:

- Read line 1 to `$0` with the first `getline`
- Read line 2 to `tmp` with the second `getline`
- Print `tmp` then `$0`, i.e. print line 2 then line 1
- Repeat with the next pair of lines: print line 4 then line 3, etc.

With an odd number of lines, the last line goes through `getline $0`, then `getline tmp` fails but you aren't checking the return status so this merely leaves `tmp` unchanged, and you end up printing the next-to-last line again.